# ¿Cómo puedo crear un bucle for para crear una lista con los p-valores que quiero de un Test Wilcoxon de ciertas columnas de dos dataframes en Python?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, dataframe, test

Muy buenas, tengo dos dataframe cada uno con las mismas columnas pero valores distintos y lo que quiero es realizar un test Wilcoxon y obtener el p-valor comparando una columna de un dataframe con la misma columna del otro dataframe.
Adjunto un ejemplo de mis datos. El primer dataframe llamado dataframe_presencial_B2:

| contador_eh | contador_uff | contador_mm | contador_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Y otro dataframe llamado dataframe_virtual_B2:

| contador_eh | contador_uff | contador_mm | contador_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |

Lo que tengo de código es esto:

```
result = stats.wilcoxon(dataframe_presencial_B2['contador_mm'], dataframe_virtual_B2['contador_mm'])
print(result.pvalue)
```

Pero claro, en mis dataframes tengo muchas más columnas a analizar entonces ir una por una es muy largo, y quería saber si es posible desarrollar un bucle for para que me aparezcan en una lista todos los p-valores por cada una de las columnas que yo quiero de mis dataframes ya que no todas me interesan. Siguiendo el ejemplo que he puesto, me interesarían solo las columnas contador_eh, contador_uff y contador_mm la de contador_a no me interesaría. Por lo que en el bucle for debería aparecer estas 3.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que hay muchas formas de hacerlo, acá propongo como calcular los valores para agregarlos a una lista primero y a un diccionario, la segunda forma lo que permite es tener rastreado que `p_value` corresponde a qué columna.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats


df1_dict = {'contador_eh'   : [1,2,1],
            'copntador_uff' : [1,1,2],
            'contador_mm'   : [1,2,1],
            'contador_a'    : [0,1,1]}

df2_dict = {'contador_eh'   : [1,1,1],
            'copntador_uff' : [1,0,0],
            'contador_mm'   : [1,0,2],
            'contador_a'    : [2,1,0]}

dataframe_presencial_B2 = pd.DataFrame(df1_dict)
dataframe_virtual_B2    = pd.DataFrame(df2_dict)

colNames = dataframe_presencial_B2.columns

#como lista
p_val_list = []
for c in colNames:
    p_val_list.append( stats.wilcoxon(dataframe_presencial_B2[c], 
                                      dataframe_virtual_B2[c]).pvalue) 

#como diccionario para tener 
# referencia de que valor corresponde a qué columna

p_val_dict ={}
for c in colNames:
    p_val_dict[c] = stats.wilcoxon(dataframe_presencial_B2[c], 
                                   dataframe_virtual_B2[c]).pvalue


print(p_val_dict)
```

Tira algunos warnings porque el test de wilcoxon tiene algún problema con "ties" no sé bien que es eso, pero será problema tuyo.

Comment: Buen día, como algo adicional, podrías convertir los resultados a un nuevo `dataframe`, saludos!

Comment: simplemente hacé `pd.dataFrame(p_val_dict)`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por vuestra ayuda, me ha sido de gran valor!! Un saludo @Ulises Bussi

Comment: @HeytalePazguato